Hacking LED power supply into battery charger
We have been bombed by Russia on weekend and have scheduled electricity. So I have to make some charging unit for LiFePO (4S, 12 V) batteries with balancer that I have. May be it would not be best or right way to do but should be ok for emergency.
I have 12 V 400 W LED power unit that has a potentiometer to tune voltage, ESP32 and shunt resistor.
How can I tinker it into constant current powersupply to charge battery at 40 A from 10 V to 14.6 V?
ChatGPT responds to replace its resistor with a digital potentiometer and measure voltage on the shunt resistor with an opamp. But it would take few days to get a digital potentiometer. I'm also not sure if a digital potentiometer really works like real potentiometer could be replaced that easy. e.g. I wonder if digital potentiometer depends on ground much.

What is the most voltage you can get from power supply?

Can you tune the current setting? Can you open it and take a photo?

Also, worst case on current limitation, do you have a high power 12 V bulb available (or several in parallel smaller ones in parallel) or a bunch of ~1 ohm resistors?

I bought a Shuriken from Thailand back to NZ in my checked baggage in 2003. I thought nothing of it and it was not commented on. Someone else ended up in court some while later for bringing in a number of different weapons. It seemed extremely perverse of the law as none were illegal per se (as far as I know). || Possible lesson: Be careful when you travel abroad :-) :-) :-) ::

If it's a supply designed specifically for LEDs, it is likely it has a CC/CV mode. The Meanwell supplies I use support this, for example.
The supply's max current already corresponds to the battery's charging current, so no need to modify this.
You can test if it is CC/CV by wiring 12V halogen bulbs from car headlights or MR16 spotlights on the output. When you get slightly above the rated current, if the power supply has CC/CV, voltage should drop to keep the current constant, but it should not turn off. It should only turn off if output voltage falls too much. Another method is to read the datasheet of course.
If it supports CC/CV, all you have to do is tweak the feedback resistor so the supply outputs the maximum desired voltage and connect it to the battery.

I'd suggest a tad under 14.6 so the battery floats if left connected at below notional Vmax. || I've found that LiFePO4 tolerate overvoltage far better than LiIon - some IC manufacturers offer a fast charge mode using only CC and terminate when Vmax is set with Vmax being slightly above what is usual. || I've found that LiFePo4 (some/all/few/???) can be taken to 4.2 V cell with minimal capacity in the 3.6-4.2 range. I've not seen this well documented AND I'm not going to recommend it here. It seems thatthere may be a small amount of material outside the olivine structure. Or ... ?

Useful to know are

Max voltage and voltage range of LED supply.

Does the supply tolerate being loaded to or beyond maximum rating.

If overloading is OK - what happens? Does the supply trip-out or decrease in voltage to limit current. The latter would be ideal.


The key things are

Limit current to some designed maximum

Do not ever charge battery to above 3.6 V/cell


LiFePO is more forgiving than LiIon of holding at maximum voltage but ideally do not do this for long periods.
Charging is usually CC/CV - constant (or <= maximum current till target voltage is reached then constant voltage until current taken by cells reduces to some target level.
If you can tolerate less than 100% charge then charging to slightly less than the usual Vmax allows floating with (essentially) no danger to the cells.
If you do this your BMS will never  "trip" if cells are well balanced.
You then get CC (roughly) as the PSU limits, perhaps with a small series R, then floating. Take the battery off float as soon as possible BUT if Vfloat is < 3.6 V/cell you are unlikely to do harm.
While it would be "nice" to control the supply voltage with your ESP that is not essential.
A digital potentiometer could be emulated using a MOSFET and PWMing the gate (possibly filtering to get a controllable gate voltage) and adjusting based on measured results BUT while this is not conceptually hard it will take between a few minutes and a full time week (Murphy says) to implement, and the rough method below will probably suffice.
It would be extremely useful to know the maximum available voltage from the LED power supply.  If it is 12V nominal as you say and 400 W then the most current you can get is I = P/V = 400/12 ~= 33 A. IF your battery can tolerate 40 A charge rate then current limiting may not be needed, provided that the power supply can tolerate being operated fully loaded or potentially more than fully loaded.
Possibly you can adjust the voltage so maximum current is not exceeded at any point. If you manually adjust Vsupply to set Imax at the start of charging current will never be higher than this.
If you need to provide a current limiting resistor then the wire from a mains electric heater is liable to be suitable. Ukraine is 230 VAC I believe. If so a 1 kW element has about R = V^2/P = 230^2/1000 =~ 53 Ω and rated to run red hot at about I = P/V ~= 4 A.
To drop say 1 V at say 30 A you need R = V/I = 1/30 = 0.03 Ω.
To carry say 2 A/strand you need at least 15 strands. But if you used the whole 1 kW wire length that gives a resistance of R = 53/15 ~= 3.5 Ω.
So you obviously need many more strands and shorter lengths.
So e.g. 20 turns between 2 conductors 1/40th of the total length apart gives you 40 strands each of 1/40th of the original resistance. So Reffective = 53/40/40 ~= 0.033 Ω.
Fortunately, to drop more voltage at that current takes higher resistance.
I have not tried this for such a low resistance, but winding the wire many times around two conductors a small distance apart will (probably :-) ) work.
E.g. two bolts bolted through an insulating sheet of thermally resistant material.
As Winny says, a bulb (or several in parallel) can be used as a series resistor. A 12 V 48 W bulb takes 4 A when hot BUT if operated at well below rated current resistance will be much lower. This means you may need a box of bulbs to get a low enough resistance, high enough current resistor.

I don't generally recommend using lightbulbs as current limiters except in times of war... :-(

@Winny Heater elements in times of war, and any other time, MAY be more suitable. Or not :-) .

@greybeard  Thanks float <-- floast.
